# expected an indented block for continue keyword in python

Tags: python, continue

I used Jupiter notebook, I am new in python, I just try this code and get error, I don't understand why i get this error

```
for i in range(1,10):
if i%3==0:
continue
print(i)
```

ERROR:File "", line 3
    continue
           ^
Indentation Error: expected an indented block

Comment: Reading out load `indentation Error: expected an indented block` might ring some bell. Just a tab key before `continue`

Comment: You have multiple indentation errors in the code you show. Is that actually the code you tried to run?

Comment: Python is a strongly typed language, the indents are important to signify which code belongs in which block.  Please refer back to your tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indented code will be:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if i%3==0:
        continue
    print(i)
```